# How can I sum common keys in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I have a pretty tricky data structure that I need to iterate over in order to produce a more concise object.

In [lodash](https://lodash.com) (or javascript if better), is there a way to generate unique key values by taking all `original.day` types and adding their `original.value` together, then merging into their given sets to create a new object;

Here is my original object, some items appear as duplicates but the values should still be added together to their corresponding day.

```
var original = [

  { day: 01, value: 0 },
  { day: 01, value: 2 },

  { day: 02, value: 4 },
  { day: 02, value: 1 },

  { day: 03, value: 3 },
  { day: 03, value: 9 },

  { day: 01, value: 0 },
  { day: 01, value: 4 },

  { day: 02, value: 2 },
  { day: 02, value: 0 },

  { day: 03, value: 3 },
  { day: 03, value: 3 }

];
```

I then need to get the following:

```
var output = [
  { day01: 6 },
  { day02: 7 },
  { day03: 18 }
];
```

or :

```
var output = [
  [01,6],
  [02,7],
  [03,18]
];
```

I have tried many different approaches with lodash (uniq,reduce,each etc...) with no joy, perhaps I'm not using the right method. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI: you are not going to get a leading zero with 01

Comment: The title of your question does not really match the output you're looking for.  The output you asked for is described more like: "Sum common keys in an array of objects".  You aren't "finding" anything "unique".

Comment: Agreed, I've updated title, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this in plain Javascript.  The creation of the `day01` style keys just takes a couple extra lines of code.  You can run this snippet here to see the result:

```js
function sumDays(list) {
    var result = {};
    list.forEach(function(item) {
        var dayNum = item.day;
        var dayPrefix = dayNum <= 9 ? "0" : "";
        var key = "day" + dayPrefix + dayNum;
        if (!result[key]) {
            result[key] = 0;
        }
        result[key] += item.value;
    });
    return result;
}

var original = [

  { day: 01, value: 0 },
  { day: 01, value: 2 },

  { day: 02, value: 4 },
  { day: 02, value: 1 },

  { day: 03, value: 3 },
  { day: 03, value: 9 },

  { day: 01, value: 0 },
  { day: 01, value: 4 },

  { day: 02, value: 2 },
  { day: 02, value: 0 },

  { day: 03, value: 3 },
  { day: 03, value: 3 }

];

var r = sumDays(original);
document.write(JSON.stringify(r));
```

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to go around with this is by using **[`_.reduce`](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce)** for lodash or **[`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** for plain javascript.

**Lodash**

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/S32vVVLmplOJ6OTmjMxP?p=preview)**

```
function getTotalDays(collection) {
  return _.reduce(collection, function(result, item) {
    var index = 'day' + _.padLeft(item.day, 2, 0);
    result[index] = (result[index] || 0) + item.value;
    return result;
  }, {});
}
```

**PLAIN JAVASCRIPT**

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/G53TudvKzaCoY9Ggxo07?p=preview)**

```
function getTotalDays(collection) {
  return collection.reduce(function(result, item) {
    var index = 'day' + (item.day < 10? '0': '') + item.day;
    result[index] = (result[index] || 0) + item.value;
    return result;
  }, {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the 2nd format `[["01",6], ["02",7], ["03",18]]`:

```
_.pairs(_.reduce(original, function(output, item) {
    var day = '0' + item.day;
    output[day] = (output[day] || 0) + item.value;
    return output;
}, {}));
```